# Insert unity as in a subview in android and plug in

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have to build an android app in which I have to integrate unity player with an existing android application. I need to get values from a sensor and animate the gameObject in unity. Should I make a plugin using ndk or jni? Please help. I'm new to this. I have read the docs but I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to build an Android Studio project instead of an APK. To do this, select the "Google Android Project" checkbox from the android build settings.

This will give you a project with a main activity which is a UnityPlayerActivity. You can add/remove activities, views and do anything you want with the project. You should also be able to move the contents to another project and merge them. The important thing here is to keep all the libraries and resources Unity builds intact. This should all feel natural if you're familiar with Android Studio.

To pass data to/from Unity, you can use the AndroidJava* classes, which essentially allow you to call any Java code (from the OS libraries or your app package) as if you were using reflection API.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this. What I wanted to know was how can I communicate with the gameObject. I've read about the UnitySendMessage method but as it is a real time application, will it be feasible to call it frequently?

Comment: Yes, it'll be alright. I don't like it though, because of how messy it is. Accidentally renaming the GameObject breaks it. What I do in my own project is to poll Java from the Unity side every frame for new data. It shouldn't matter that much, unless you have way too much data to move around each frame.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. :-)

Comment: Hi, there is another problem. Whenever I have to make changes in unity project I have to export the project again. How do I merge the new exported project with the previous one so that I don't have to copy files again and again?

Comment: Create an automatic script which does the copying for you. Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html